# Stripe - Create a Payment Intent for a Draft Invoice - PHP

Tags: stripe-payments, invoice

When upgrading a subscription I create a draft invoice which "pulls in all pending invoice items on that customer, including prorations":

```
//upgrade subscription with new plan
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subscription_id);
$subscription->plan = $plan_id;
$subscription->proration_date = $proration_date;
$subscription->save();

//create invoice for outstanding amount on subscription
$inv = \Stripe\Invoice::create(array(
     "customer" => $customer_id
));
```

Then I flag the subscription to allow incomplete payments (necessary to deal with cards that need authentication):

```
//Flag to allow incomplete payments
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_id, [
          "payment_behavior" => "allow_incomplete"
     ]);
```

Then I collect payment:

```
//collect payment immediately (note: fails when authentication needed and creates a payment intent)
$inv->pay();
```

Then I retrieve the payment intent:

```
//retrieve payment intent ID (note: DOESN'T WORK - THE LATEST INVOICE SHOWS AS AN OLD ONE)
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_id, [
          "expand" => ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"]
     ]);
```

**So instead of using `$inv->pay()` is there a better way to create a payment intent for the draft invoice that will enable retrieval of the payment intent?**

Note that in the above code the Payment Intent is created after the payment attempt fails (it can be viewed in Stripe Dashboard). **If there is no alternative to `$inv->pay()` how can I retrieve the payment intent instead of using `"latest_invoice.paymentintent"`?**

**UPDATE**

Rather than trying to retrieve the payment intent via `"latest_invoice.paymentintent"` (see comment as to why) I am trying to retrieve it from the invoice using this code:

```
$updated_inv = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($invoice_id); //NOT WORKING

$intent = $updated_inv->payment_intent;
```

However, $updated_inv is empty so the retrive is not working...

Comment: The `$inv` and the `$subscription.latest_invoice` are two different invoices. `$inv` is a onetime invoice might contain all the unpaid items belong to the customer while the subscription invoice is only for the subscription although it is possible these two have the same amount if subscription happens to be the only unpaid item. And for onetime invoice and subscription, they could be paid using different card depends on how your subscription is created. 
So really you should only use `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent` to drive your subscription payments.

Comment: Thanks for this - it explains why `$subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent` is not showing the correct invoice number (it is the last, already paid, invoice on the subscription). Note however, that I am updating the subscription to use the card supplied at upgrade (via elements and stripe.js) so the new card will drive all payments. I also want to take payment immediately so that 1) people can't upgrade for free and then cancel later in the month 2) people can verify while on-session if authentication is needed. Therefore I need a way to return the payment intent for the one-time invoice.